# php IMAP connect to hotmail

Tags: php, imap, pop3

I am using imap_open to connect to my hotmail account. Now I want to check list of all folders like inbox, junk, sent etc. using imap_list() like this.

```
<?php
   $mbox = imap_open("{pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl}", "username", "password")
     or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

    $boxes = imap_list($mbox, '{pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl}', '*');

    print_r($boxes);
    imap_close($mbox);
 ?>
```

but it shows only Inbox. Actually I want to check mails in the junk folder.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$server = '{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/ssl}';
$connection = imap_open($server, $username, $password);
$mailboxes = imap_list($connection, $server,'*');
print_r(imap_errors());
print_r($mailboxes);
imap_close($connection);
```

It's worked for me and hope it'll help someone :)

Comment: Works as of November 2021; remember your username must be the *full email address* as it is possible to have an hotmail or outlook address with the same username. If the script doesn't respond then you're likely using a VPN which they hard blocked a spammer.

Comment: Just a note for those still having trouble(s): you must enable IMAP settings on your account in order for this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This Code Is Not My Own As I Pulled It From php.net. But I Can Say It Will Work.

```
<?php

     //check for new messages 

     $mailbox = imap_open("{localhost/pop3:110}INBOX", 
             "#username#","#password#"); 

     // Check messages 
     $check = imap_check($mailbox); 
     print("<PRE>"); 
     print("Date most recent message : " . $check->Date); 
     print("<BR>"); 
     print("Connection type : " . $check->Driver); 
     print("<BR>"); 
     print("Name of the mailbox : " . $check->Mailbox); 
     print("<BR>"); 
     print("Number of messages : " . $check->Nmsgs); 
     print("<BR>"); 
     print("Number of recent messages : " . $check->Recent); 
     print("<BR>"); 
     print("</PRE>"); 

     // show headers for messages 

     $index=1; 

     $header = imap_header($mailbox, $index); 
     print("<PRE>"); 
     print("Header Date : " . $header->Date . "<BR>"); 
     print("Header To : " . $header->to) . "<BR>"; 
     print("Header From : " . $header->From . "<BR>"); 
     print("Header cc : " . $header->cc . "<BR>"); 
     print("Header ReplyTo : " . $header->ReplyTo . "<BR>"); 
     print("Header Subject : " . $header->Subject . "<BR></PRE>"); 

     print("<PRE>"); 
     print(imap_body($mailbox,$index)); 
     print("</PRE><HR>"); 

     imap_close($mailbox); 

?>
```

Hope That Helps A Bit.

Comment: I want to check mails in the junk folder. for that I am using "{pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl}Junk" as a host name but it not working and if I want to show the list of folders in hotmail it shows only inbox...

Answer (score 0):

change `imap_list($mbox, '{pop3.live.com:995/pop3/ssl}', '*');` to  `imap_list($mbox, '{pop3.live.com}', '*');`

no need for port or connection protocol...